# How to execute a command after an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I wrote this script:

```
$.getJSON('<%=Url.Action("JsonSave","Controler")%>', {
    id: newRow.Id,
    personId: newRow.PesronId},
    function(data) {
        $('#grid').trigger('reloadGrid'); //{0}
        $('#grid').editRow(rowCount); //{1}
    })
})
```

What should I do so that **{1}** would be executed exactly after **{0}**?

Comment: Is it not executing in that order?

Comment: no its not. i guess the trigger is async

Comment: @CoffeCode, hope I didn't send you on a wild goose chase. I did some research and have updated my answer with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ANSWER UPDATED** I did a little research, and it seems you are using the [jQuery Grid plugin](http://www.trirand.com/blog/). It has a callback called `gridComplete` that should do what you need. Combine that with my original answer to use `one` and you will be all set:

Since events are called in order, you could add your method into the event queue like this:

```
$.getJSON('<%=Url.Action("JsonSave","Controler")%>',
        { id: newRow.Id, personId: newRow.PesronId},
         function(data) {
            $('#grid').one('gridComplete', function(){ $('#grid').editRow(rowCount); });
            $('#grid').trigger('reloadGrid');
         })
```

Using the [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) causes your event callback to be used only once.

Comment: thanks for the update, 
i tried it but still no result, im gettin realy confused

Answer (score 1):

Doug's answer is right except the event to be used is `loadComplete`

[jQGrid documentation for events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events)

Comment: @Vinodh, from the event list it seems that `loadComplete` fires after the XHR request returns, but before the Grid is updated. His call to edit the row would fail because it would be updated after the event ended. `gridComplete` is the correct event AFAIK.

Comment: In my experience of using jqGrid, I have always seen `loadComplete` execute after `gridComplete`. Not sure of the reason. But for the purpose of this discussion I tested the call to `editRow` and it works whether it is placed in `gridComplete` or `loadComplete` events.

Answer (score 0):

Are `trigger()` and `editRow()` asynchronous calls? If so, you may be out of luck doing it this way, as you don't know when they will be called.

If you need `editRow()` to be called after `trigger()` completes, make the call to `EditRow()` at the end of the `trigger()` function itself.